# How to make CMake use environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH and C_INCLUDE_DIRS

Tags: build, cmake, environment-variables

Is there a way to pass C_INCLUDE_DIRS and LD_LIBRARY_PATH from cmake command line or is there a way to set env so that CMAKE can find and use them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is not fully clear what you intend to do with these variables. Here are some possibilities:

1. Inside a CMake script you can read environment variables using the syntax `$ENV{<VARIABLE_NAME>}`. So in your `CMakeLists.txt` you can have something like

   ```
   message( "Found environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" )
   ```
2. If you want to add the location contained in this variable to be available to your CMake target executables and libraries then you can use the [link_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html?highlight=link_directories) command as

   ```
   link_directories( $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} )
   ```
3. Or if you have someone else's project and you want to instruct CMake to look for libraries in some additional directories you can use [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) or [CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html). For example to pass these variables in a command line you could do

   ```
   cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/custom/location
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One should care when use an environment variable which denotes **path** and want the project to work on Windows. The problem is with a **path separator**: CMake uses forward slash, `/`, but Windows uses backslash, `\`.

For convert a path from the native (OS-specific) to the CMake, one may use [file(TO_CMAKE_PATH)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#to-cmake-path) command flow:

```
# Save environment variable into the CMake but with the proper path separator
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "$ENV{SOME_PATH_VAR}" SOME_PATH_VAR_CMAKE)
# Following commands could use the created CMake variable
include_directories(${SOME_PATH_VAR_CMAKE})
```

Also, `find_*` commands (e.g. [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/command/find_path.html)) have PATH and HINTS options, which can transform paths from environment variables automatically, using `ENV <VAR>` syntax:

```
find_path(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY # Result variable
    mylib.h # File to search for
    HINTS ENV SOME_PATH_VAR # Take a hint from the environment variable
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the (seems to me anyway) obvious thing with them, which is to get `find_library` and `find_path` to find things located therein, I finally figured out that you should use the `INCLUDE` and `LIB`. This is [mentioned in the docs for `find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html#:%7E:text=Search%20the%20standard,UNIX%20based%20platforms) but it's not obvious that those are environment variables. So, e.g.:

```
export LIB=$LIB;$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export INCLUDE=$INCLUDE;$C_INCLUDE_PATH;$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Would maybe get you where you want to be.