# CMake Issues with find_path()

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following part of a findPackage.cmake

```
 find_path(CoinUtils_INCLUDE_DIR
              NAMES CoinUtilsConfig.h
              HINTS ${COIN_INC}
              PATH_SUFFIXES coin
              DOC "CoinUtils include directory.")
    
 message(${CoinUtils_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I get the following message

```
CoinUtils_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

when I try to check the value of the `${COIN_INC}`, I have

```
$ echo ${COIN_INC}
/usr/local/dist/include/coin-or
```

when I `ls *.h` the `/usr/local/dist/include/coin-or`, I get

```
ClpConfig.h          CoinTypes.h          OsiClpConfig.h       OsiGlpkConfig.h
Clp_C_Interface.h    CoinUtilsConfig.h    OsiConfig.h          OsiUnitTestsConfig.h
```

I feel like it should work but I am not sure why I am not able to set the `CoinUtils_INCLUDE_DIR` variable.

Comment: I only wanted to show the contents of ${COIN_INC} to show that `CoinUtilsConfig.h` is present

Comment: Please note, that `${COIN_INC}` dereferences a **CMake** variable. If you want to dereference environment variable, instead `HINTS ${COIN_INC}` use `HINTS ENV COIN_INC`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks! I found out that there is a `CMakeSettings.txt` and I could set the ${COIN_INC} variable there. Thanks a lot! Please write this as answer and I will accept.

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate for one, which describes using an environment variable in CMake. Also, I have added [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66535178/3440745) about using environment variables in `HINTS` or `PATHS` options.